# Ito multiplication

Tags: itos-lemma

Let $\{N_t|0<t\leqslant T \}$  and $\{M_t|0<t\leqslant T \}$ be two Poisson processes with intensities $\lambda_n, \lambda_m>0$, respectively.

Based on the implicit results of Corollaries 1 and 2 of [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/45130507_Ito%27s_Lemma_and_the_Bellman_Equation_for_Poisson_Processes_An_Applied_View) and Theorem 1 of [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165188906000893), I think we should be able to write $$dN_t dM_t = 0.$$

Can anyone please help me with the proof of this equation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*If* $M$ and $N$ are *independent* (your references appear to make this assumption), then $M+N$ is also a Poisson process. So, using the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation#Definition):

$$ dMdN = 2^{-1}\left[(d(M+N))^2 - (dM)^2 - (dN)^2\right] $$

$$ = 2^{-1}\left[d(M+N) - dM - dN \right] = 0 $$

(A proof of $(dX)^2 = dX$ for a Poisson process $X$ is available [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3308123/26651).)

Comment: Great answer (+1)! It made me think: For a Brownian motion, we have $dWdt=0$, $dW^2=dt$ and $dW^3=0$. Are there analogues for Poisson processes? Your link suggests $dN^2=dN$ and $dN^3=dN$, etc.? What about cross-terms like $dNdt$ or $dWdN$ (if $W$ and $N$ are independent)?

Comment: @Alex Yes, $(dN)^3 = (dN)^2\cdot (dN) = dN\cdot dN = dN$.  And, yes, based on the so-called "Ito multiplication table for Brownian motion and jumps" (aka "and Poisson process"),  the two cross-terms you mentioned are 0. Make the cross-terms a SE Quant question if you are looking for some sort of proofs or proof references.

Comment: @Alex This [resource](https://personal.ntu.edu.sg/nprivault/MA5182/stochastic-calculus-jump-processes.pdf) has the table, Table 20.1 (but not the cross-term proofs, I think).

Comment: cool, thank you very much for the table. That's really interesting. Thank you!

Comment: @ir7 Great help, thank you. You mentioned this result holds when $N$ and $M$ are independent. Could you please guide me through the calculations when they're not? For example, if $N_t \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda t)$ and $M_t \sim \text{Poisson}(\theta \lambda t)$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @VultraUiolet Make it a SE Quant question, basically, how does one create correlated Poisson processes (common shock model comes to mind; just stating different constant intensities does not imply process dependence) and then how does one compute their quadratic covariation.